# flot graphs timestamp problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I got a graph showing bugs and passes of test suits I run, now they got a unix timestamp and a int containing the number of passes/bugs made I want to show a trend during a months period passes vs bugs. the data set looks like this:

```
var datasets = {
        "Pass": {
            label: "Pass",
            data: [[1382099410000, 4], [1382185810000, 0], [1382272210000, 7], [1382358610000, 2], [1382445010000, 4]]
        },
        "Bug": {
            label: "Bug",
            data: [[1382099410000, 0], [1382185810000, 1], [1382272210000, 5], [1382358610000, 0], [1382445010000, 0]]
        }
    };
```

they ate used in this example http://jsfiddle.net/2dHVY/5/ I only cover 5 days but the timestamps are shown all wrong, the dates are suposed to be 18/10 - 22/10 but the grapsh dont show the 18:th and it shows duplicates eaven tho they got the exact same timestamp for the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot is using it's own internal algorithm to place ticks along the xaxis.  It places them at N distance apart based on the width of the chart.  You, however, want the times to be treated like categories (I have one data point for each day).  Your "duplicates" are a point at the start of a day and another at the end of a day.

You have two options.  [Hardcode your ticks](http://jsfiddle.net/2dHVY/6/) where you want them:

```
xaxis: {
  mode: "time",
  color:"#299a0b",
  tickColor: "#fff",
  timeformat: "%y/%m/%d",
  ticks: [1382099410000,1382185810000,1382272210000,1382358610000,1382445010000]
}
```

Or switch to a category xaxis.

Comment: Was exactly what I was looking for, categories it is :D